# JSON transformation in node.js

Tags: json, node.js, transform

I want to transform my data from one json structure to another. What is the best way to do it?

Here is my original resource (customer) structure is:

```
{
  "id": "123",
  "data": {
    "name": "john doe",
    "status": "active",
    "contacts": [
      {
        "email": "john@email.com"
      },
      {
        "phone": "12233333"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I want to change it to:

```
{
  "id": "123",
  "name": "john doe",
  "status": "active",
  "contacts": [
    {
      "email": "john@email.com"
    },
    {
      "phone": "12233333"
    }
  ]
}
```

Keeping in mind that I might have an *array* of resources(customers) being returned in GET /customers cases. I want to change that to an array of new data type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here I have used `Object.assign()` it will be helpful to you

```js
var arr={
  "id": "123",
  "data": {
    "name": "john doe",
    "status": "active",
    "contacts": [
      {
        "email": "john@email.com"
      },
      {
        "phone": "12233333"
      }
    ]
  }
}
arr=Object.assign(arr,arr.data);
delete arr['data'];
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Acutely, that cood is cleaner than myin

Answer (score 4):

If customer object is array of object then below will help you to get desire format result

```
var result = customerObj.map(x => {
  return {
    id: x.id,
    name: x.data.name,
    status: x.data.status,
    contacts: x.data.contacts
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to Json.parse the json into variable, and then loop through the array of objects, changes the object to the new  format, and then JSON.stringify the array back to json.

### Example code

```
 function formatter(oldFormat) {
    Object.assign(oldFormat, oldFormat.data);
    delete oldFormat.data;
}

let parsedData = JSON.parse(Oldjson);

//Take care for array of results or single result 
if (parsedData instanceof Array) {
    parsedData.map(customer => formtter(customer));
} else {
    formatter(parsedData);
}

let newJson = JSON.stringify(parsedData);
console.log(newJson);
```

### Edit

I made the formatter function cleaner by using Kalaiselvan A code